# Why is it おいしかったです and not おいしかったでした?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, tense

There are a few other questions related to this, but they do not explain the why of the matter.

As I understand it です is present tense while でした is past tense. As such, I would (wrongly) intuit to say おいしかったでした, i.e., where both おいしい and です are changed to the past tense.

I tried to ask Japanese friends and they did not really know the answer. The argued that "if おいしい is in paste tense, です doesn't need to be because おいしい already is". But by that logic why is it not おいしいでした for example.

Clearly past tense works a little bit differently then I am used to, but I have not found an explanation of this anywhere. If anybody has a detailed answer or can link to a clear source, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. です comes after nouns/na-adjectives in non-past tense, でした comes after nouns/na-adjectives in past tense, and です comes after i-adjectives in both tenses (in the polite register).

Comment: @Riolku Yes, but this question is about WHY it's so, and there is a historical reason.